# Would Phoenix Ashes Have Magical or Healing Properties?

Tags: harry-potter, phoenix

Previous questions about the Phoenix are [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9378/will-a-phoenix-eventually-die-a-natural-death) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8659/why-didnt-the-basilisk-bite-in-book-two-destroy-the-horcrux). I noticed there's a fair amount of [potions ingredients](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/magic/potions/potions-i.html) that come from creatures or animals and wondered if Phoenix **ashes**, knowing what we do about Phoenixes from *HP* canon, would have magical, particularly healing, properties. The Phoenix is reborn from its ashes each burn cycle; there must be some magical property on a fundamental level that allows the essence of the Phoenix to take corporeal form time and again. As it is continuously stated that the Phoenix is reborn from its ashes, the ashes seem an integral, if not *the* essential, component to the Phoenix's life cycle.

**Would Phoenix ashes have magical or healing properties?**

Comment: They cam magically separate fools from their gold: "[Phoenix Ashes Vial Necklace With Wing Charm](http://www.etsy.com/listing/79575788/phoenix-ashes-vial-necklace-with-wing)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing that I could find in canon/JKR info.

However, one would imagine if there were properties, Professor Slughorn would have tried to obtain them in HBP, which we don't see happening - if so, Dumbledore or Harry (under Felicis) would have used them as bait.

Out of universe:

> As described by ancient Roman writer Lucan, phoenix ashes are a crucial ingredient in a mythological resurrection potion  (src: "Kronzck, Allan Zola and Elizabeth Kronzck. The Sorcerer's Companion: A Guide to the Magical World of Harry Potter". 2nd ed. Broadway Books: New York, 2004, p209).

Answer (score -1):

Phoenix tears are well known for their healing attributes and used in the cannon, I believe the magical properties are all within the bird.  The ashes are more like a shed snake skin.

Comment: Can you back this up with canon source? That would be great.